# Find all positive integer $n$ such that $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ contains a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Find all positive integer $n$ such that $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ contains a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$

A subring a subset of the ring such that it is closed under addition, contains the identity of the ring, closed under multiplication, and closed under additive inverses.

So we want a subring isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_2,+)$, then $n = 2k$. The identity of $\mathbb{Z}_{2k}$ is $0$ since $a+0 = 0+a = a$. How do we describe the inverses for the subring?

Comment: in the last paragraph, shouldn't it be $\mathbb{Z_{2k}}$? in that case, the subring should be $ \{0,k\]$ where $0$ is the identity and $k$ is its own inverse (under addition).

Comment: If a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ contains $1$, then it is equal to $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Can you conlcude now?

Comment: @shrey I'm not familiar with what ${0,k]$ means. What is meant by the bracket? Crostul, you mean, if a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ contains the identity element of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$?

Comment: There are two possible questions here, and it might be worthwhile to confirm which flavor is appropriate.  Suppose that $R$ is a ring with identity and $S$ is a subring.  Sometimes subrings are required to have the same identity element as the original ring, so that the identity of $S$ is the identity of $R$.  On the other hand, sometimes subrings are just subsets which are also rings (with the same operation).  In this case, the identity in $S$ (if it exists) does not need to be the same as the identity in $R$.

Comment: @shrey Both ends should be curly brackets.  It should read $\{0,k\}$.

Comment: @abstractGone: yeah, apologies for that,  it is $ \{0,k \} $.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I was reading the definition from here: http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/ideal/ideal.html which I took to mean that the identity element of $R$ must be in $S$ ("the zero element of $R$ is in $S$"). So we now know the subring of $\mathbb{Z}_{2k}$, but I don't think I understand why this answers the question. Would that mean that all $n=2k$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ contains a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$?

Comment: Be careful, the identity element is the $1$ in a ring, not the zero.  Since rings may have two identities (additive and multiplicative), we call $0$ the zero and $1$ the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some confusion in the original posting.  The question asked for a subring $S$ of $R=\mathbb{Z}_n$ that included the identity.  Through the comments, it appears that the OP wanted the additive identity to be included in the subring, not the multiplicative identity.  I will provide discussion of both ideas here.

If $S$ must contain the multiplicative identity, $1$, then $S$ contains all sums of $1$ with itself, in other words, all the elements of $R$.  Hence, if $1\in S$, then $S=R$.  The only way for $S\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2$ is if $R=\mathbb{Z}_2$.

If $S$ does not need to contain the multiplicative identity, then for $S$ to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, then $S$ must have two elements.  It has the $0$ of $R$ because $S$ is a ring and it has one other element, which we'll call $g\not=0$.  Since $S\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $S$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, it must he that $g+g\equiv 0\pmod n$ and $g\cdot g\equiv g\pmod n$.

Since $g+g\equiv 0\pmod n$ and $g\not=0$, we know that $n\mid 2g$ and that $2\mid n$.  Therefore, $n=2k$ for some $k$.  Assuming, without loss of generality that $0<g<n$, then $2g<2n$, so the only way for $n$ to divide $2g$ is if $n=2g$.  In this case, we know that $g\equiv k=\frac{n}{2}\pmod n$.

Since $g\cdot g\equiv g\pmod n$, $g\not=0$, $n=2k$, and $g\equiv k\pmod n$, we consider $k^2$.  If $k$ is even, then $n=2k\mid k^2$, which cannot happen because $g\cdot g\equiv g\not\equiv 0\pmod n$.  Therefore, $k$ is odd.  Since $k$ is odd, $k=2l+1$ for some integer $l$, then $k^2=k(2l+1)=2kl+k=nl+k\equiv k\pmod n$.  Therefore, when $k$ is odd, $k^2\equiv k\pmod n$.

Combining all of this, we have that when $n=2k$ where $k$ is odd.  $R=\mathbb{Z}_n$ has the subring $S=\{0,k\}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my confusion! I understand now.